# Drop Down field to only show available unique integers Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

I am working on a Rails app and am not really sure where to start with tackling this problem. I have a Items Model that has a few fields, one being `order`. the `order` attribute is Unique so there can only be one `1` and one `2` etc...

I am looking to create a input field that will look through my DB, see what integers are not taken (they're available), and have a select drop down helper that will only show those available numbers.

**ItemsController:**

```
def new
  @item = Item.new
  @itemCount = Item.count
end
```

**Form Partial**

```
<div class="col-lg-2">
    <%= casein_select f, f.object, :order, (1..(@itemCount + 1))  %>
</div>
```

**Model**

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
  validates :order, uniqueness: true
end
```

*P.S: I am using a CMS called [Casein](https://github.com/russellquinn/casein). It shouldn't affect it.*

Comment: Hi, You didn't mention the max value of the `order`. Please provide the `min` and `max` value of the range.

Comment: The min Value is 1, and Max is 100.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

**ItemsController**

```
def new
  @item = Item.new
  @order_collection = (1..100).to_a - Item.all.pluck(:order)
end
```

**Form Partial**

```
<div class="col-lg-2">
  <%= casein_select f, f.object, :order, @order_collection  %>
</div>
```

I hope this would be helpful